# MYSQL: Exclude Rows in join if row in join table matches

Tags: php, mysql

let's say i have the following two tables:

```
Table Orders
ID | Order_ID | Products_ID
1       a          22912
2       b          22912
3       c          22912

Table Products
ID     | more stuff
22912     lorem ipsum
```

So far really easy. With joins i can get every info i want. But i want a joined query thats returns Null if a Product has a order from a sepcial order id. That means if i get a match on order id then null should be returned for the product.

i tried in different ways:

```
SELECT * FROM Products p JOIN orders o ON p.ID=o.Products_ID WHERE Order_ID !='a'
```

with that i'll get the 2 for b & c order id.

Allright next try:

```
select * from Products p JOIN (select * FROM Orders o WHERE WHERE Order_ID !="a") jo ON p.ID=jo.Product_ID
```

Hmm same query, same result. Result should be empty if one Order_ID matches. Anyone an Idea how to solve that within one query. I think the second query is the key but how to write the subquery that it returns empty result?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Products p JOIN orders o ON p.ID=o.Products_ID WHERE o.Order_ID !='a'` ?

Comment: Yesterday I was working on an assignment and I came across a same like problem. I think the thing that is making this *glitch* is because products_ID is a row with only the same values and the other 2 tables have different values. Joining that causes problems since the data is the same in 1 column and not the same in a other

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia: Same than my query. You have just replace the quote marks from " to '. But thats not the Prob. I have change in my question.

Comment: i want a joined query thats returns Null if a Product has a order from a sepcial order id. - is not at all clear. Are you saying that if you get a match on order id then null should be returned for the product?

Comment: @P.Salmon: That's it. Sorry for unclear question. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the case statement, check the below code

```
 SELECT 
case
    when o.Order_ID = 'a'
        then 'null'
    else
        o.Order_ID 
end as orderId
 FROM Products p JOIN orders o 
 where p.ID = o.Products_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT  * FROM  orders o  Left JOIN   Products p ON p.ID=o.Products_ID and o.Order_ID !='a'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

SELECT TEMP.* FROM (SELECT p.*,o.ORDER_ID FROM Products p JOIN orders o ON p.ID=o.PRODUCT_ID WHERE o.Order_ID ='a') as TEMP WHERE TEMP.ORDER_ID !='a'

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.*, null as somecolumn
from p
join o on o.products_id = p.id
where o.order_id = 'a';
```

Returns

```
+-------+-------------+------------+
| ID    | morestuff   | somecolumn |
+-------+-------------+------------+
| 22912 | lorem ipsum |       NULL |
+-------+-------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Fulfills your requirement *if i get a match on order id then null should be returned for the product*.But that doesn't make sense to me and there does not seem to be a relationship other than by product between orders a,b,c